# Dropwizard default logback pattern

Tags: java, logback, dropwizard

Does anyone knows the default format pattern for Dropwizard 0.7.1 logging, if no logFormat is configured?

I need sth like:

```
%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%X{id}] [%X{format}] [%thread]: %class{0}::%method:%line - %msg%n
```

Comment: According to the source code `io.dropwizard.logging.DropwizardLayout`, it's 

`%-5p [%d{ISO8601," + timeZone.getID() + "}] %c: %m%n%rEx`. As I'm not sure about timeZone and whether the other lines before setPattern are relevant or not, so leaving this as comment.

Comment: @user3280180 - if this was solved, please mark the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Logback uses implementations of the [Layout interface](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/24707be9f6ca0bc303a4f234b280c058fcb513ac/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/Layout.java)'s `doLayout()` method to translate logging events to Strings that can be output, as outlined in [the documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html). [Dropwizard provides an extension](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-logging/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/logging/DropwizardLayout.java) to the [`PatternLayout` class](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/24707be9f6ca0bc303a4f234b280c058fcb513ac/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/PatternLayout.java) (which is in turn an extension of the [abstract `PatternLayoutBase` class](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/24707be9f6ca0bc303a4f234b280c058fcb513ac/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/pattern/PatternLayoutBase.java)):

> `PatternLayout` takes a logging event and returns a `String`. However,
>   this `String` can be customized by tweaking PatternLayout's *conversion
>   pattern*.

```
public class DropwizardLayout extends PatternLayout {
    public DropwizardLayout(LoggerContext context, TimeZone timeZone) {
        super();
        setOutputPatternAsHeader(false);
        getDefaultConverterMap().put("ex", PrefixedThrowableProxyConverter.class.getName());
        getDefaultConverterMap().put("xEx", PrefixedExtendedThrowableProxyConverter.class.getName());
        getDefaultConverterMap().put("rEx", PrefixedRootCauseFirstThrowableProxyConverter.class.getName());
        setPattern("%-5p [%d{ISO8601," + timeZone.getID() + "}] %c: %m%n%rEx");
        setContext(context);
    }
}
```

What this does is:

1. Ensures that `outputPatternAsHeader` is disabled, which is a flag that outputs the String pattern that you want at the top of any logs. One way to confirm the pattern used could be to enable this flag on your appender, as outlined in [the logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/encoders.html#outputPatternAsHeader).
2. Overrides a number of [*conversion words*](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord) related to printing exceptions to use [an implementation of ThrowableProxyConverter](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-logging/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/logging/PrefixedThrowableProxyConverter.java) that prefixes the stack trace with exclamation marks.
3. Set the pattern to be `"%-5p [%d{ISO8601," + timeZone.getID() + "}] %c: %m%n%rEx"`, using the timezone passed in. If you don't add the timezone information explicitly, logback will use the JVM's timezone, or else GMT. If this is acceptable, you could just use `%d`, as the `ISO8601` format is the default.
4. Sets the context.